# Why is my site showing multiple broken links in tools when they are all working?

Tags: html, apache, redirect, http-status-code-404, sitemap

We have built a new site warmseal.westserve.co.uk. When we run it through broken link checker tools it is showing that we have multiple broken links which in reality work.

For example the following link in the top-wrapper is showing as a broken link:

```
<a href="/callback/" id="call-back" class="left"><img src="/templates/images/phone.png" class="icon" />Request a call back<img class="arrow" src="/templates/images/arrow-right.png"/></a>
```

Any ideas why some links are showing as broken links?

What actions are needed to stop them showing as broken links?

There is also an issue with XML sitemap tools not picking up all of the pages. I think this is related and by solving the broken links issue it will solve the other.

I have tried making all pages on the site have a trailing / on the end as somebody suggested this may help but this makes no difference and still doesn't work.

Comment: Stop using broken link checker. It´s useless in this context.

Comment: those are absolute links, you should use relative links `./templates` instead.

Comment: @Jacobson — The link checker is fine. The server is responding with bad data.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson — There is nothing wrong with using absolute paths in URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing `http://warmseal.westserve.co.uk/callback/` (using [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)) shows that your server is responding with a `404 Not Found` status code with an HTML document (that appears to be the desired page) as the human readable error message.

Comment: Hi - I'm having exactly the same problem.  How does one fix this?

Comment: @TomChambers — The same way you fix any 404 Not Found error. You use the correct URL or you put some data at the URL you are using.

Comment: Hi Quentin - thanks i realise that but i dont understand why my page is link is displaying the correct page to a human but giving a 404 server response.  to do with routing i imagine but wondered whether the original asker had a routing issue